# Fancybox + Flexslider only works if content not initially hidden

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, flexslider

I'm wondering if anyone can shed some light on why this isn't working for me. I'm trying to get a Flexslider gallery working within a Fancybox lightbox. Everything works until I try hiding the gallery content on initial load.  I've put together a simple fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/skube/THyYe/1/) to illustrate. Everything works (aside from initially showing the gallery content). When I uncomment the following line in CSS to hide the gallery, and re-run, it breaks.

```
/* #gallery {display: none;}  uncomment to see not working */
```

Comment: so, does it work? any feedback will help you more than me ;)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Flexslider uses its own methods to calculate the size of the view port and then the size of slider in an attempt to be responsive. If the parent container is *hidden* (`display: none`) then Flexslider fails with such calculations hence is not displayed in fancybox.

If you open your own http://jsfiddle.net/skube/THyYe/1/ and resize the results window, you will see that Flexslider is shown after re-calculating the view port.

As a workaround, I would initialize Flexslider **inside** a fancybox's callback instead. Also, I would use a Flexslider's callback to make the parent container visible so the size calculation won't fail like this :

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    // optionally set dimensions
    // you may need to adjust these settings
    // width : 400, // or whatever needed
    // height: 300,
    autoSize: false, // keep this and let the slider to resize itself
    afterLoad: function () {
        $('#slider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            start: function () {
                $("#gallery").show() // make parent container visible
            }
        });
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aw3kb/)**

Comment: i ran into a pretty similar issue a while ago. i fixed it by making the parent div style `position:absolue;top:-1000px`. then from flexslider `start` callback, i removed the style so dom structure is back to normal :)